# BDDMockito 1.9.5 test for Exception from a void method

Tags: java, mockito

My Customer class looks like

```
public class Customer {
    private String age;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

and CustomerValidator to check if age is less than 999 is as follows

```
public class CustomerValidator {

    private final Pattern rxNumOnly3 = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,3}$"); // only 3 digit

    public void validateCustomer(Customer customer){
        if (customer != null  && !rxNumOnly3.matcher(  customer.getAge() ).matches()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Age should be less than 3 digits");
        }
    }
}
```

My CustomerValidatorTest class is as follows :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomerValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    private CustomerValidator customerValidatorMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void validateCustomer(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        Mockito.doNothing().doThrow(new RuntimeException("Exception caught") ).when(customerValidatorMock).validateCustomer(customer);

        customer.setAge("1234");

        customerValidatorMock.validateCustomer(customer);

    }
}
```

I am trying to test the validate method when age is 123 & 1234. 
Currently the test case is a pass in the above use cases.

Can anyone please give some inputs where in the test fails when age is 1234 & test passes when age is 123 ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you mock the method you're testing? That makes no sense. All you will do by doing that is testing Mockito instead of testing your code. You don't need any mock to test this validator. Just create one by calling its constructor, the call its validate method, and check it throws or not an exception.

Comment: I have a validator class(CustomerValidator) for customer and it is called in other registration related transactions. My intention was to create a stub for the validator in CustomerValidatorTest and run it as part of maven build process. There is existing code using code try {
            customerValidatorMock.validateCustomer(customer);
        }catch (GeneralDataError exp){
            errorDesc=exp.getMessage();
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(errorDesc);
        Assert.assertEquals("Error occurred", errorDesc); I was trying to come up with a much shorter code. But didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is this test code supposed to test? What do you want to verify in this test?

Comment: The test code must throw an error(Hence assertion passed) when age is 1234. Else otherwise.

Comment: So, just use `@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class) public void shouldRejectAge1234() { Customer c = new Customer(); c.setAge("1234"); new CustomerValidator().validateCustomer(c); }`.

Comment: Getting error   java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException

 at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
 at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I copied and pasted your code, without doing any modification. Then I created a test and pasted **my** test method, without doing any modification, and the test passes.

Comment: Can you please share the test code snippet ?

Comment: I already did. It's in my previous comment. Just put that in a public class named, for example, CustomerValidatorTest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want test some object, you can't mock it. So in easiest way, your test should contain two method. First method should check that validation pass when you age is valid. Second method should check that validation fail when age is not valid.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import pl.mkorwel.spock.test.Customer;
import pl.mkorwel.spock.test.CustomerValidator;

public class CustomerValidatorTest {
    CustomerValidator customerValidator = new CustomerValidator();

    @Test
    public void shouldPassValidationWhenCustomerHasValidAge(){
        //given
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setAge("123");

        //when
        customerValidator.validateCustomer(customer);

        //then
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void shouldFailValidationWhenCustomerHasInvalidAge(){
        //given
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setAge("1234");

        //when
        customerValidator.validateCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

As you see, in that case you don't need `Mockito`.

Of course it is only sample, in that case probably you can use parameterized tests.

Comment: Thanks. The explanation makes sense, now.